# What sites exist for posting client proofs?

Tags: workflow, web

As I'm doing more and more photo shoots, I'm looking for a site in which I can post proofs for clients to look at.  I would use Flickr, however the images can be downloaded and I obviously don't want proofs to be downloaded before they have been edited.  Can anyone recommend a site that I can use?

Answer (score 6):

**SmugMug.com** for sure.  Tons of security features both to protect the photographer's work (right click protection, watermarking, image size limitations) and to protect privacy (password protected galleries, password protected sites, unlisted galleries).  Not to mention all the commerce features and other Pro oriented stuffs.

http://www.smugmug.com/help/private-search-island

NOTE: I am a SmugMug employee :D

Comment: This is great....thanks very much for your recommendation!  I'll take a look at it later today.

Comment: Note - @Shizam is employed by them.

Comment: I sure hope you started working at SmugMug *after* you provided this answer. ['...the community frowns on overt self-promotion and tends to vote it down and flag it...'](http://photo.stackexchange.com/faq#promotion)

Comment: This post was about 1 year ago (why does it say Oct 2010 though??), I don't know what the state of that FAQ was back then and you'll note I updated the answer immediately after dpollitt pointed out this answer's state.

Answer (score 4):

Along with SmugMug, Zenfolio and PhotoShelter also has the same features, so compare them and find one that suits your needs.

Answer (score 1):

Many options exist for this, and over time these company's seem to come and go but I'll note some of the recent ones that I am familiar with:

- [Zenfolio](http://www.zenfolio.com/)
- [Instaproofs](http://www.instaproofs.com)
- [Smugmug](http://www.smugmug.com/)
- [aPhotoFolio](http://aphotofolio.com/)
- [ShowItFast](http://showitfast.com/)
- [Photobiz](http://www.photobiz.com/)
- [Photocart](http://www.picturespro.com/i/photo_cart/)
- [ShootProof](http://www.shootproof.com/)
- [Photoshelter](http://www.photoshelter.com/)
- [Livebooks](http://www.livebooks.com/)
- [Redcart](http://redcart.com/) - Shopping Cart
- [Photography Orders](http://www.photographyorders.com/)
- [ProPhoto Blogs](http://www.prophotoblogs.com/explore-features/) - Can be used for proofing but not technically what you asked for.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try Pixoasis.com.

Answer (score 0):

ACDSee Pro comes with an online feature (ACDSeeonline.com) that allows you to share selectively and you can choose whether to allow downloads of images, etc. Unlike the other sites you can manage your photos online from within the app.