# Wedding photography business website software

Tags: software, web, business, wedding

I have been running my own wedding photography business for a couple of months.

One thing I'm struggling with is how to create my website so that clients can purchase packages and photos from me.

I have had at a look at a few options, but not really sure which ones do the job.

Does anyone have any recommendations?

Comment: Basically you want a combination of http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/4341/what-sites-exist-for-posting-client-proofs and http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/12497/what-solutions-are-available-for-a-self-hosted-portfolio-website

Answer (score 2):

Product recommendations are not generally in scope for the QA format as they tend to be very dependent on the time that they are asked.  There are however a decent number of commercial services that can handle this kind of situation.  SmugMug is the first one that comes to mind.

Comment: +1 for SmugMug and for pointing out that the poster is asking for opinions and not facts.

Comment: thanks for the answer. Sorry for posting in the wrong exchange. Please feel free to suggest an alternative

Comment: @Gaz_Edge - it isn't that it's the wrong exchange, just in general StackExchange prefers questions that have lasting value and are not time sensitive.  For example, a better question might be something like "How to find a good photo storefront?" or "What should I look for when selecting a photo storefront?"  These questions have lasting value since what makes a good service and how to find one generally don't change over time.  SmugMug is good today, but if they decided to triple their prices tomorrow, then they wouldn't be good anymore.